# User LogIn on Android using Parse

Tags: android, mobile, parse-platform

I am working on an android application, where user information is stored on cloud database(**Parse**) and I am using those values for user identification. However I am unable to fetch user info (user name & password )in an android if else statement. Please find the code attached below.

```
private void userScreen() {
                EditText username = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.userName);
                String username1 = username.getText().toString();
                EditText password1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.password);
                String userpassword = password1.getText().toString();
                ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("UserInfo");
                if ((query.whereEqualTo("user_name", username1);) && (query.whereEqualTo("password", userpassword));){

        } 
    }
```

I am getting **error** in **If statement** at **'&&'** .. " **is not a valid parse operator** "

Can any one please provide me a solution for this problem.

Answer (score 1):

That's not how you call Parse Queries. If you want both conditions to be true you would write it like so:

```
ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("UserInfo");
query.whereEqualTo("user_name", username1);
query.whereEqualTo("password", userpassword);
query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {
public void done(List<ParseObject> results, ParseException e) {
    if (e == null) {
        if (results.size() > 0) {
            // query found a user
        }
    } else {
        // error
    }
}
```

I think a better option would be to use the [`Parse Login`](https://parse.com/docs/android_guide#users-login) functionality.

```
ParseUser.logInInBackground("UserName", "Password", new LogInCallback() {
    public void done(ParseUser user, ParseException e) {
        if (user != null) {
            // Hooray! The user is logged in.
        } else {
            // Signup failed. Look at the ParseException to see what happened.
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: No, not the error message but i doesn't solve my problem. I need to validate user input and open new activity accordingly.              Thanks for the help

Comment: I added a check that might help you understand. The query does work. I think that it's wrong to use a query in this situation. What are you trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 0):

I think Dehli's answer is correct, but if you want to start another activity if, let's say the user already exists, then you should handle that in the else clause inside

```
ParseUser.logInInBackground("UserName", "Password", new LogInCallback() {
public void done(ParseUser user, ParseException e) {
    if (user != null) {
        // Hooray! The user is logged in.
    } else {
        // Signup failed. Look at the ParseException to see what happened.
//here is where you should handle your stuffs. Look at the e.getMessage() or the errorID
    }
}
```

});